# Determining the number of dimensions of an Ada array

Tags: arrays, ada

Is it possible to determine the number of dimensions of an Ada array at runtime? For example, given the array type

```
type int_int_array is array (1 .. 3, 1 .. 4) of integer;
```

I'm looking for some attribute or combination of attributes I could use to determine that the array has 2 dimensions. The end goal is really to iterate over the entire array but all the ways of doing this  I'm aware of only work if you know the dimension count ahead of time. The array's definition (including the number of dimensions) is going to be changing quite a bit during some current development and I'm hoping I don't have to update every piece of code that iterates over it every time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will always know it, so there is no need to ask at run-time.

Comment: My problem is that quite a few places want to iterate over the entire array. During development over the last couple weeks, the array dimensionality has gone from 1 to 2 to 3 and back to 2, and this is going to keep going on as some stuff is being tuned. The iterator code can use the 'range attribute to deal with changing ranges but I was hoping there was a way I could avoid touching every piece of iterator code whenever the dimensionality is updated.

Comment: Maybe you should have asked about that in the question, then.  The solution is trivial in Ada 2012: `for E of Array_Instance loop ... end loop;`

Comment: That works, thank you. I grew up with Ada95 where apparently that wasn't a construct. Also, no offense, but did you miss the last sentence of my question? It's essentially the same as my previous comment.

Comment: It is useful to follow the development of the language.  The quick "upgrade" path is probably to read the rationales for Ada 2012 - and maybe also that for Ada 2005.  (And yes, I did notice the last sentence in the question - even the first time I read it.)